# Find a recurrence relation that gives a formula for the number of arrangements of wins and losses for aN (you stop playing at 3 losses in a row).

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, combinatorial-proofs

**Problem**

Since it’s a wise idea to have a stopping condition when gambling, a gambler decides to play a game until they lose three times in a row. Let W and L denote wins and losses respectively, and let aN denote the number of arrangements of wins and losses over N games.
Here are the possibilities for the arrangements of wins and losses for the first values of aN:

a3 = 1  (LLL)

a4 = 1  (WLLL)

a5 = 2  (WWLLL, LWLLL)

a6 = 4  (WWWLLL, WLWLLL, LWWLLL, LLWLLL)

etc…

Bearing in mind that any sequence of N games must start with the arrangement W, LW, or LLW, find a recurrence relation that gives a formula for the number of arrangements of wins and losses for aN.

**Solution**

So, I know that for N > 3, the arrangement of wins and losses must end with WLLL.

There are two arrangements of 5 games (WWLLL, LWLLL), four arrangements of 6 games (WWWLLL, WLWLLL, LWWLLL, LLWLLL), seven arrangements of 7 games, thirteen arrangements of 8 games, and 24 arrangements of 9 games. I am trying to find a pattern based on the total number of arrangements of wins and losses minus the arrangements with three L's in a row. I have: 2^(N-4) arrangements for N > 3 (subtract 4 from N because you will always end with WLLL), but am having difficulty finding the number of arrangements with 3 L's.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: The hint pretty well solves the problem.  The ones that begin with $W$ must be any "good" string of length $n-1$ (with a $W$ prepended).  Similarly the ones that begin with $LW$ must be any "good" string of length $n-2$ (with an $LW$ prepended) and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building from what lulu wrote in the comments, we have:
$$
a_N=a_{N-1}+a_{N-2}+a_{N-3}
$$
so you simply add the three previous figures. The reason is as lulu stated:

- Good strings of length $N$ starting with $W$ can be formed from good strings of length $N-1$ by prepending $W$.
- Good strings of length $N$ starting with $LW$ can be formed from good string of length $N-2$ by prepending $LW$.
- Good string of length $N$ starting with $LLW$ can be formed from good strings of length $N-3$ by prepending $LLW$.

That's all. Thanks to lulu.